# In Windbg what command will display all function names or addresses that call a specific function?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, windbg

I need to obtain the addresses (absolute) of all functions that call the below function. Can this be done in Windbg ?

The function that I would like to find all callers of is KeBugCheckEx

```
lkd> uf nt!KeBugCheckEx
```

Comment: There is no such command. Runtime-calculated indirect calls would make this impossible to do statically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cannot be a realistic requirement

KeBugCheckEx is an exported Function as such it can be called by AnyOne who wants to call it

```
dumpbin /exports c:\Windows\System32\ntoskrnl.exe  | findstr "KeBugCheckEx"
       1114  442 003F8FA0 KeBugCheckEx
```

over and above as commented by Raymond chen indirect calls are not resolvable statically

still if you want to go ahead try this

this may scrap around 50% hopefully :)

```
0: kd> lm m nt
start             end                 module name
fffff800`73800000 fffff800`74846000   nt         (pdb symbols)          f:\symbols\ntkrnlmp.pdb\68A17FAF3012B7846079AEECDBE0A5831\ntkrnlmp.pdb
0: kd> .hh
0: kd> # KeBugCheckEx fffff800`73800000 L?(fffff800`74846000-fffff800`73800000)
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for volmgrx.sys
nt!ExAcquireFastMutexUnsafe+0x12f:
fffff800`73a0971f e87cf81e00      call    nt!KeBugCheckEx (fffff800`73bf8fa0)
nt!MiIdentifyPfn+0xd1b:
fffff800`73a0d94b e850b61e00      call    nt!KeBugCheckEx (fffff800`73bf8fa0)
nt!ExAcquireFastMutex+0x14a:
fffff800`73a0dbaa e8f1b31e00      call    nt!KeBugCheckEx (fffff800`73bf8fa0)
nt!ExAcquireCacheAwarePushLockSharedEx+0x14a:
fffff800`73a0df1a e881b01e00      call    nt!KeBugCheckEx (fffff800`73bf8fa0)
nt!ExAcquirePushLockExclusiveEx+0x146:
fffff800`73a0e4b6 e8e5aa1e00      call    nt!KeBugCheckEx (fffff800`73bf8fa0)
nt!ExAcquirePushLockSharedEx+0x13d:
fffff800`73a0e66d e82ea91e00      call    nt!KeBugCheckEx (fffff800`73bf8fa0)
nt!ExReleaseResourceLite+0x18d:
fffff800`73a0ef7d e81ea01e00      call    nt!KeBugCheckEx (fffff800`73bf8fa0)
nt!ExAcquireResourceExclusiveLite+0x2eb:
```

:>python -c print(len((open('callkebug.txt','r')).readlines()))
3224

[image]